# Generating a flavored signed APK with android studio vs ./gradlew assemble[FlavourName]Release provides different results

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest, travis-ci, android-productflavors

I have an android app with 2 flavors (build variants) that i successfully manage to build and generate a signed APK from via:
 Android Studio -> build -> generate signed APK

When i try to do the same via CLI (./gradlew assemble[FlavourName]Release) i manage to get an APK but it cannot be installed on a device/emulator.

After looking at the generated AndroidManifest.xml of the 2 APK's i see that the one generated with CLI is missing all the specific flavor entries (including the LAUNCHER intent and thats why the APK is not running)

The CLI is used to build the APK on Travis CI

Im guessing that the merging process of the AndroidManifest files is not happening right for some reason. Anyone has any idea why? or what else could have gone wrong?

CLI generated Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="xxx.xxx.xxx" platformBuildVersionCode="23" platformBuildVersionName="6.0-2704002">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<application android:allowBackup="false">
    <activity android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="xxx.xxx.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="xxx"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value="xxx"/>
    <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.gms.permission.BIND_NETWORK_TASK_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_TASK_READY"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <meta-data android:name="com.dylanvann.fastimage.OkHttpProgressGlideModule" android:value="GlideModule"/>
    <activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <provider android:authorities="xxx.xxx.xxx.crashlyticsinitprovider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="100" android:name="com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider"/>
</application>
```

Android studio Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="xxx.xxx.xxx" platformBuildVersionCode="23" platformBuildVersionName="6.0-2704002">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<permission android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<application android:allowBackup="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_xxx" android:label="@string/xxx" android:largeHeap="true" android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx.MainApplication" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <category android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationRegistrationService"/>
    <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:label="@string/xxx" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="xxx"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
    <activity android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="xxx.xxx.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="xxx"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value="xxx"/>
    <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.gms.permission.BIND_NETWORK_TASK_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_TASK_READY"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <meta-data android:name="com.dylanvann.fastimage.OkHttpProgressGlideModule" android:value="GlideModule"/>
    <activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <provider android:authorities="xxx.xxx.xxx.crashlyticsinitprovider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="100" android:name="com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem was the name of the flavor being all capital letters while the path library name was written in lowercased. On my Mac the Gradle had no problem with the difference but apparently on travis it didn't find the library :(

Hope this will help someone in the future.